# DataTable with pipelined server-side processing drops local changes when redrawn?

Tags: datatables

#### Background

I have a DataTable with some widgets (actually Font Awesome icons with click handlers) [rendered inside it](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to toggle the "state" of backend entities represented by rows in the table.

The table is populated using the `serverSide: true` functionality so that pages are pulled from the backend (ultimately using SQL `LIMIT`s), rather than loading the whole lot then paging it in the browser.

I'm also using "[pipelining](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)" to get pages from the server in (small) chunks rather than literally one at a time.

Some code:

```
$(function() {
   $('#myTable').DataTable({
      columns: [
         { data: "id" },
         {
            data: "state",
            render: function(data, type, row) {
               if (type === 'display') {
                  if (data === true) {
                      return '<i title="On" data-id="' + row["id"] + '"'
                         + ' class="fa fa-check-circle toggle_off" />';
                  }
                  else {
                      return '<i title="Off" data-id="' + row["id"] + '"'
                         + ' class="fa fa-check toggle_on" />';
                  }
               }

               return data;
            }
         }
      ],

      serverSide:  true,
      deferRender: true,
      ordering:    false,
      searching:   false,
      pageLength:  25,

      ajax:        $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
         url: "/backend/getData"
      })
   });

   // (We'll see what setState is in a moment)
   $('.toggle_off').on('click', function() {
      setState([this.dataset.id], false);
   });

   $('.toggle_on').on('click', function() {
      setState([this.dataset.id], true);
   });
});
```

With the backend returning data like this:

```
[
   {"DT_RowId": 1, "id": 1, "state": true},
   {"DT_RowId": 2, "id": 2, "state": false},
   {"DT_RowId": 3, "id": 3, "state": false},
   {"DT_RowId": 4, "id": 4, "state": true}
]
```

and the HTML looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="datatables.js" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="myTable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>State</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody />
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

*(Obviously a live testcase is impossible without a working backend data source.)*

#### What I'm doing

When I perform one of these toggles, I don't need to reload the entire dataset/page, as I know exactly how the affected row will change. So I did the following:

```
/**
 * Sets the state of one (or more!) entries, immediately reflecting
 * those changes in the table if successful (without requiring a fresh
 * backend table retrieval).
 */
function setState(row_ids, bool) {
   var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
   var rows  = table.rows(row_ids);

   $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      method:   "POST",
      url:      "/backend/setState",
      data:     { row_ids: row_ids }
   })
   .done(function(data) {
      // Change successful; update table to match
      rows.every(function() {
         var d = this.data();
         d["state"] = bool;

         // Commit by invalidating DT's cache for this row
         this.invalidate();
      });

      // Now redraw per docs
      table.draw(false);
   })
   .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
      alert("State change failed");
   });
}
```

#### The problem

However, I've observed that though the `this.invalidate()` call has an immediate graphical effect, it is not persistent: changing to another page and back loses the change, and the immediate call to `.draw()` (per docs) also puts the data back to the state it was in when retrieved from the backend.

I guess doing an AJAX reload would work, as the backend itself now reflects the state I've just changed the row to, but I don't want to have to do that.

How can I commit this local change to data retrieved from the server?

Comment: Since it took me 24 hours followed by 6 hours sleep followed by 1 hour followed by drafting this SO question to find the problem, I figured someone may as well benefit from it ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Caching, naturally.

---

Your cocktail of server-side rendering and pipelining rubs up against the doc examples slightly.

Although the `this.invalidate()` call does "commit" the change into DataTables's own cache, you're forgetting about the pipeline cache, which still contains state as last retrieved from the backend. Perhaps unintuitively, a `draw()` in `serverSide` mode apparently performs an AJAX reload as well, but then you're hitting the pipeline cache and getting old state.

To fix this, you could invalidate the pipeline cache too:

```
function setState(row_ids, bool) {
   var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
   var rows  = table.rows(row_ids);

   $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      method:   "POST",
      url:      "/backend/setState",
      data:     { row_ids: row_ids }
   })
   .done(function(data) {
      // Change successful; update table to match
      rows.every(function() {
         var d = this.data();
         d["state"] = bool;

         // Commit by invalidating DT's cache for this row
         this.invalidate();
      });

      // Don't redraw now, but clear pipeline cache otherwise
      // our local changes will be lost the next time we do
      // (unless there is a cache miss for some reason and the
      //  new state is pulled from the backend)
      table.clearPipeline();
   })
   .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
      alert("State change failed");
   });
}
```

Though this will require an AJAX reload on the next `draw()` or when you next change pages. An alternative would be to extend the pipeline code to allow for direct modifications to its cache, much like you're doing to DataTables's cache already.

Comment: Oh also giving `'page'` to the draw command (`draw('page')`) may have helped - the way it was, a re-order & re-search would be triggered (even though I have both disabled), which with `serverSide:true` would require a query to the backend (or, in your case, to the pipeline's caching layer, hence the bug). As it is, though, it seems an immediate `draw` isn't needed at all.

Comment: Or `invalidate('data')` _maybe_. Not sure on that one.